# Which Monospace fonts pair well with Seravek ExtraLight?

Tags: font-recommendation, monospace, font-pairing

### My personal case

Seravek has **restrained shapes** and **medium width**.

However, most popular monospace fonts (Courier New, Menlo, etc) are **too wide** or/and **too exaggerative**. So I need a monospace font that is neither too wide nor too exaggerative; fitting the temperament of Seravek.

I was using *Seravek Light* in my blog; *Inconsolata* integrated fine with it. Now I’m considering to use *Seravek ExtraLight* instead, but confused by the monospace-font issue.

[image]

### To be general

Although my personal case is to find one to work as inline pieces of code in articles, please make your answer general for other usages, e.g. headlines, outdoors, advertising, package design, etc.

Comment: Seravek is **not** a "built in OSX family". I don't have it. [List of OSX fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_OS_X) and for reference: [Seravek from Process Type](https://processtypefoundry.com/fonts/seravek/)

Comment: @Scott The list is **up to 10.7**, whereas Seravek can be seen in 10.9. (Not sure 10.8 yet.)

Comment: I'm running 10.10.2 and I don't see it. It's not a big deal. I just thought you should be aware that it's not part of OSX as far as I'm aware. It is far more likely you acquired the font, than it is that the OSX installer failed to install it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Courier** as the basis for comparison, the criteria were:

- less wide than Courier
- less exaggerated (more constrained) than Courier

Based on this criteria, I would suggest experimenting with the following monospace fonts:

## [**Ubuntu Mono**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ubuntu-mono)

Has a nice high x-height with a bit of a condensed look and a few different cuts to use.

[image: Ubuntu Mono Font Screenshot]

## [**Audimat Mono**](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Audimat-Mono)

A bit less condensed than Ubuntu, but with double the number of cuts, and a relatively contemporary look for a monospace

[image: Audimat Mono Font Screenshot]

## [**Code New Roman**](http://www.dafont.com/code-new-roman.font)

A monospace that tries to look like a regular font, bit older, but still a goody

[image: Code New Roman Font Screenshot]

## [**Monofonto**](http://www.1001fonts.com/monofonto-font.html)

This is one of my personal favorites. It barely resembles a monospace, but it is, which by all functional purposes is amazing.

[image: Monofont Regular Font Screenshot]

Hopefully you'll be able to find a resource here that can help you out. All the best!

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll start to compare them tonight : )